# Java problems in Grails application imported in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, grails

I imported a Grails application in Eclipse. It was a new setup, so I installed Java 8 first. I started getting **Java Problems** marker. Reading online I found out it might be a compatibility problem with Java 8, so I removed it and installed Java 7. But the problem persists. The weird thing is that `run-app` command runs fine and I can use the application without any issue. I am using Grails 2.3.5.

Comment: Are you using STS or eclipse for J2ee.. Use eclipse STS for grails application..

Comment: I am using ggts plugin for eclipse.